# Delete the "Temp" folder?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I know that the "Temp" folder is the place where Windows and the installed programs save their temporary files.

Is there a tool that could delete all temporary files on my Windows 7 system?

Answer (score 10):

People often forget that Windows does have a cleanup utility :

- In Windows Explorer, right-click the
  disk and select Properties
- Click the "Disk Cleanup" button and
  wait for it to analyze the disk
- It will then display several
  categories and the amount of disk-space
  that you will save per each.
  Clicking on each category displays a helpful description.
- The category you are looking for is "Temporary files".
  Place a check-mark on it and click OK.

Comment: sounds very good on paper, but these MS "tools" leave a lot of files and folders

Comment: In Windows 7, run the cleanup as user and then as system cleanup to get maximum effect. It does the job pretty effectively as long as each user account takes care of their own.

Answer (score 8):

There are several applications that does this. A few examples are [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and [Disk Cleanup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Cleanup) that ships with Windows.

Answer (score 2):

- In Windows Explorer go to %temp%
- Select all Files (Ctrl-A) and press Shift-Delete
- If it complains that it can't delete a file (because it's in use) just select 'Skip'.